# remove leading "./" in a batch script

Tags: bash, scripting, sox

```
for f in ./*.mp3; do sox "$f" "${f%%.mp3}processed.mp3" silence 1 0.02 1% -1 0.02 1%; done
```

This is a script I'm using to process audio files. The problem is that it keeps going in a loop, processing the new audio files as well. I'd like to fix this by having the output go in a subfolder, so I tried this:

```
for f in ./*.mp3; do sox "$f" "/subfolder${f%%.mp3}processed.mp3" silence 1 0.02 1% -1 0.02 1%; done
```

This is the output:

```
/subfolder./01processed.mp3
```

This is giving me an error with Sox, I need to remove the ./ before the filename output, how might I do that? This is the output I'd like to have:

```
/subfolder/01processed.mp3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for f in *.mp3; do sox "$f" "/subfolder/${f%%.mp3}processed.mp3" silence 1 0.02 1% -1 0.02 1%; done
```

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't work, however by adding a leading "." now it works. 'do sox "$f" "./subfolder/${f%%.mp3}processed.mp3" silence 1 0.02 1% -1 0.02 1%; done'

Comment: @Marw Don't add a ".", remove the "/" (that is, use `"subfolder/${f%%.mp3}processed.mp3"`).

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in ./*.mp3; do
    out=${f#./}
    out=${out%%.mp3}processed.mp3
    sox "$f" "/subfolder/$out" silence 1 0.02 1% -1 0.02 1%
done
```

You can strip both the leading `./` and trailing `mp3`, but parameter expansions need to be done one at a time (they can't be nested). You *could* strip only the leading `.` and keep the `/` for when you build the output path, but it's clearer to take it out and put it back explicitly. (`/subfolder$out` doesn't make it clear that a file is being put in a folder named `subfolder`, rather than making a file/folder named `subfolder$out`.)

Incidentally, `for f in ./*.mp3` is the most correct version, since it will work with files that start with `-`; otherwise, `sox` may mistake the input file name for an option.

Comment: You don't actually have to remove anything. `subfolder/./file` is perfectly fine